# Is there any way to specify the file name to read using byte streams within the source code in java?

Tags: java

**Background**

From the examples that I've seen so far, when you read files using byte streams in java, you have to specify the file name in command prompt. I writing a Java program that I need the file name to be specified in the source code. For example:

```
/* Display a text file. 
To use this program, specify the name of the file that you want to see. 
For example, to see a file called TEST.TXT, use the following command line. 
java ShowFile TEST.TXT 
*/ 
import java.io.*; 
class ShowFile { 
public static void main(String args[]) 
throws IOException 
{ 
 int i; 
FileInputStream fin; 
try { 
fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]); 
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
return; 
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
System.out.println("Usage: ShowFile File"); 
return; 
} 
// read characters until EOF is encountered 
do { 
i = fin.read(); 
if(i != -1) System.out.print((char) i); 
} while(i != -1); 
fin.close(); 
} 
}
```

**Question**

Is there any way to specify the file name to read using byte streams within the source code?

Comment: What examples are you talking about? Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

The first google result for "java open file byte stream" shows you how to do this. And it's the main [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Edit:
Based on your code sample

```
fin = new FileInputStream("myFilenameExample");
```